# How to avoid image overlap of label.image when new image is created at regular intervals in vb .net

Tags: vb.net, image

Ive created a label that is truly transparent using the below codes. By truly transparent I mean, even if the background of the label changes, the label remains transparent. Something that cannot be achieved using the conventional method i.e. using transparency key.

```
Dim Source_point As Point = New Point(Me.Left + 128, Me.Top + 57)
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(ScreenGrab)

    g.CopyFromScreen(Source_point, Point.Empty, ScreenGrab.Size)

    LabelBatteryLevel.Image = ScreenGrab
```

The above codes are within a timer.Tick sub. Ive used timer so as to update the image of the label when the background changes. Now the problem is, after every interval of the timer, the item(image) of `LabelBatteryLevel.Image` gets recreated and overlaps the the image created at the previous interval. This looks shabby at runtime. How do I remove the image created at previous interval before a new image gets created in the next interval?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Graphics.Clear Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.clear(v=vs.110).aspx) before drawing another image.

```
Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(ScreenGrab)

g.Clear(transparencyKeyColor)
g.CopyFromScreen(Source_point, Point.Empty, ScreenGrab.Size)
```

Comment: Where exactly should I place _g.Clear(transparencyKeyColor)_ in the codes mentioned in the question? I placed it right below the declaration of _g_ and its not working.

Comment: Just before drawing the new image (before `g.CopyFromScreen(...)`). This clears the old image.

Comment: Where are you copying the new image from? If the screen region overlaps with the label image, then of course the old image it will be part of the new image, but not as a result of drawing, because you are copying it. Try `LabelBatteryLevel.Image = Nothing` before `CopyFromScreen`.

Comment: Reading your comment, I get the problem. Anyways using `LabelBatteryLevel.Image = Nothing` did not work but `LabelBatteryLevel.Text = ""` worked. Thank you.